# Massive ScriptResource.axd - is this caused by ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, fiddler

I'm running fiddler against my live website which uses a bit of ASP.NET AJAX and a bit of query. I'm noticing a MASSIVE ScriptResource.axd file of 300KB

Starts off like this

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
// Assembly:    System.Web.Extensions
// Version:     3.5.0.0
// FileVersion: 3.5.30729.196
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// MicrosoftAjax.js
// Microsoft AJAX Framework.
```

Is this just the weight of the ASP.NET AJAX Javascript library?

Comment: Do you use a scriptmanager of any kind? Could be this combines all ajax script files in one big request.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to switch your javascript libraries to non-debug versions. They are a lot smaller in size.

Comment: Also, ensure that you've enabled HTTP Compression on your server. A 300k plaintext script file will be about 60kb compressed with GZIP.